# How to install dependencies from package.json?

Tags: android, ios, angular, visual-studio-code, nativescript

So, I have a NaticeScript project which requires a bunch of modules. I'm familiar with Node.Js but new to NativeScript. Here's my package.json. I'm not able to run the project because it doesn't have all the modules.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@proplugins/nativescript-dom": "^2.2.1",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-master-technology": "^1.2.0",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-permissions": "^1.5.0",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-platform-css": "^1.8.0",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-purchase": "^4.0.1",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-zxing": "^1.7.0",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.3",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "is-integer": "^1.0.7",
    "is-number": "^7.0.0",
    "is-positive-integer": "^1.1.1",
    "is-url": "^1.2.4",
    "js-seeder": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-appavailability": "^1.3.2",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.4.2",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^6.1.1",
    "nativescript-effects": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-image": "^3.0.5",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "^4.0.3",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
    "nativescript-plugin-universal-links": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^8.1.0",
    "nativescript-vibrate": "^3.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

How do I install all of these dependencies? My node version is 8.9.4 and the NPM version is 5.6.0. Please don't ask why don't I have the latest. Please, suggest ways with NPM and not with HomeBrew etc.

I have even tried:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-platform
npm i
```

And possibly everything.
But this complains that nativescript-globalevents isn't found and when I install globalscripts, it complains platform isn't found!

I even tried adding modules one by one but it'd give me error all the time

```
npm install @proplugins/nativescript-globalevents@1.3.0 --save
```

This results in: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @proplugins/nativescript-globalevents@1.3.0
Just an FYI: I already have the nativescript installed v6.8.0
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using a package from [ProPlugins](https://proplugins.org/).

As per their site: ProPlugins is a curated, tested, documented, demo'd, highly supported group of NativeScript plugins; from the top trusted authors in the community.

You will need to [pay them a subscription](https://proplugins.org/subscribe.html) if you want to access their curated plugins.

The reason why you are getting the `ERR! 404 Not Found: @proplugins/nativescript-globalevents@1.3.0` is because you don't have access to the private repository. Hence the status 400+.

Answer (score -1):

Try `$ tns install [--path]`
--path - Specifies the directory which contains the package.json file, if different from the current directory.

For a specific module `tns install <Module>`

The documentation is https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/configuration/install

Comment: Already tried that. Comes back with same error:

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @proplugins/nativescript-globalevents@1.4.1